# Format JSON Resulting expression

Tags: json, spring, rest, jaxb, jersey-2.0

I'm writing a REST api using Jersey2 and Spring and I would like to format the resulting JSON expression to something more specifique and I don't know if I'm supposed to modify structure of my POJO or format the response on the ressource

Actual JSON

```
Response [ {
   "rcId" : 22900,
   "posId" : 595,
   "status" : "PERC6",
   "dateFrom" : 1438380000000,
   "dateTo" : 1442095200000,
   "creaDate" : 1442349754000
   "createdBy": "52e28419-2c48-526d-8e7c-783cf331e071",
   "modifiedBy": "52e28419-1725-84bd-9884-6969e7b9b876",
} ]
```

Wanted formated JSON

```
Response [ {
   “results”: {
      "rcId" : 22900,
      "posId" : 595,
      "status" : "PERC6",
      "dateFrom" : 1438380000000,
      "dateTo" : 1442095200000,
      "creaDate" : 1442349754000
      "createdBy": "52e28419-2c48-526d-8e7c-783cf331e071",
      "modifiedBy": "52e28419-1725-84bd-9884-6969e7b9b876",
   }
   "related": {
      "52e28419-2c48-526d-8e7c-783cf331e071":  { "user/username" : "test" }
      "52e28419-1725-84bd-9884-6969e7b9b876": { “user/username” : “test” }
   }
   "errors": [ ... If errors while executing query... ]
}
```

My object looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="STATUS")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RcPosStatus implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8039686696076337853L;

@Id
@Column(name="RC_ID")
@XmlElement(name = "RC_ID") 
private Long rcId;

@Column(name="POS_ID")
@XmlElement(name = "POS_ID")    
private Long posId;

@Column(name="STATUS")
@XmlElement(name = "STATUS")    
private String status;


@Column(name="DATE_FROM")
@XmlElement(name = "DATE_FROM") 
private Date dateFrom;

@Column(name="DATE_TO")
@XmlElement(name = "DATE_TO")   
private Date dateTo; 

@Column(name="CREA_DATE")
@XmlElement(name = "CREATION_DATE")   
private Date creaDate;
```

My resource

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<RcPosStatus> getRcPosStatus(
        @QueryParam("orderByInsertionDate") String orderByInsertionDate,
        @QueryParam("numberDaysToLookBack") Integer numberDaysToLookBack)
        throws IOException, AppException {
            List<RcPosStatus> status = statusService.getRcPosStatus(
            orderByInsertionDate, numberDaysToLookBack);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you create DTOs (Data Transfer Objects). You should not change the data model to represent the outcome of the REST endpoint. The reason for this is because requirements in the clients change over time and it's important to have a solid model that is stable.

It is a matter of architecture how you want to organize the DTOs, here is an example if I understand your model correct:

```
public class DefaultResponseDTO<Foo, Bar> implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<Foo> results;
    private ArrayList<Bar> related;
    private ArrayList<Errors> errors;
    ...
}
```

Now using it to create the response you want

```
... //fetches data from resources and starting to map response.
DefaultResponseDTO<Pojo, Pojo> response = new DefaultResponseDTO();
response.results = results; //some results you want to return, Entities
response.related = releated; //some results you want to return as related, Entities
response.errors = errors;
return response;
```

Using generics lets you create a default response that suits your needs, and helps you to keep a clean and neat API. Here is a list object I like to use, that has meta data about the list that I use in the clients for paging: http://pastebin.com/mTU4qbc7

Comment: Tkx Gulbrandsen, that's clearly what I was looking for